# Anomalies on boundary and bulk physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topological-field-theory, quantum-anomalies, quantum-hall-effect

Few times I faced with such statements:

> The **gravitational anomaly** of the 1+1d boundary system is known to be
>   proportional to the thermal Hall conductivity of the 2+1 dimensional
>   bulk

**How gravitational anomaly arise in this statement?**

Naively, I expect that **chiral anomaly** is related to Hall conductivity:

$$
\partial_\mu J_A^\mu \propto F_{01}
$$

Or in therms of partition function (under chiral transformation) this look like:

$$
Z(\alpha) = e^{i\alpha\int d^2 x F_{01}} Z(0)
$$

If we provide this 2d to be bound of some 3d bulk, gauge transformation of 3D abelian Chern-Simons theory (which famously related to quantum Hall effect) is proportional to same phase (with specifications about boundary):

$$
\delta_\alpha \int d^3x \varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho} A_\mu F_{\nu\rho}
=
\int d^3x \varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho} \partial_\mu \alpha F_{\nu\rho}
=
\alpha \int d^2x F_{01}
$$

**So, how different anomalies related to bulk physics?**

Answer (score 3):

You can try reading my paper "Gravitational Anomalies and Thermal Hall effect in Topological Insulators" (arXiv:1201.4095) It addresses exactly this issue.

The simple statement is that the bulk thermal Hall effect is related to the edge gravitational anomaly is correct  as long as you realize that the bulk energy flow requires a tidal force (ie something proprtional to the Riemann curvature $R$) and not just a gravitational potential gradient (proportional to the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma$)
The original gravito-magnetic statement that says that even at $T=0$ there is a *bulk* energy  current when a topological insulator is in a gravitational field is incorrect. There is a thermal current at the edge only. In this the physics is different from the ordinary Hall effect in which there can be both an edge and bulk current.

Comment: Thank you for link! It will be very helpful if you formulate here main statement that answer my questions and illustrate it by some simple intuitive example. Also, could you specify what is different between gravitational and chiral anomaly in application to quantum Hall?

Comment: The simple statement is that the bulk thermal Hall effect is related to the  edge gravitational anomaly is OK as long as you realize that the bulk energy flow requires tidal force  (ie $\propto R$) and not just a gravity force  $(i.e \propto \Gamma)$. The original  gravito-magnetic statement as made in several places is wrong.

Comment: @mikestone Yes, do add at least your comment above - people are voting to delete your answer.

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify, how in this picture Riemannian curvature arise?

Comment: The energy momentum that flows into the 1+1 dimension edge from the bulk is proprtional the Scalar curvature $R$. To derive this gravitational anomaly inflow takes  several pages of algebra.  The curvature can be thought of as mathematical trick, due to Luttinger,  for computing themal conductivity.  Luttinger  combines the the fact that in equilbrium in a gravitational field the temperature varies with the gravitational potential due to red-shift. Then an Einstein argument relates the thermal conductivity to the gravity-gradient induced energy flow.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give some pedagogical reference on this topic?

Comment: There is no good pedagogical source. You have to read the papers.